# Build Visual Studio Projects from Jamfiles?

Tags: visual-studio, export, visual-studio-project, jam

Anyone know of a way to create Visual Studio Projects from a build based on Jamfiles?

I'd settle for a jamfile -> XML-or-some-other-intermediate-format exporter tool, so I could write my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jam distribution has a tool that does that:

http://redmine.jamplex.org/

See here:

http://redmine.jamplex.org/git/jamplus/docs/html/jamtoworkspace.html

Haven't used any of it myself yet, so I'm afraid I can't say anything about how well it works.

Comment: The provided links do not work... site unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). CMake files are about as [easy to write](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html) as Jamfiles, and CMake can generate projects for Visual Studio, Xcode, and Unix Makefiles automatically. I used to use Jam for all my Linux projects, but once I discovered CMake, I haven't gone back.

Comment: What CMake has in common with Visual Studio?

Comment: CMake can generate Visual Studio projects (in addition to Xcode and Unix Makefiles) from its project files. If you are developing cross-platform code, it's essentially a cross-platform project system, and much easier to use than maintaining parallel projects on each platform.

Comment: @Robert.K, why the downvote? According to http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down, "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." My answer provides an alternative way of generating a Visual Studio project that people might find informative. It may not be the answer the OP was looking for, and perhaps should be a comment instead, but it is not sloppy, lacking effort, or incorrect.

Comment: I can remove downvote. But still the question was about jamfiles and Visual Studio. I don't find you answer particularly helpful. Why even mention about CMake? What would you say if someone put information about any other tool that exports to Visual Studio project format?

Comment: @Robert.K, I'm sorry you didn't find my answer helpful. I was merely trying to spread information that people interested in converting projects to Visual Studio might find useful. If someone mentioned another tool that exports to Visual Studio, I would thank them for making me a little more informed.

Answer (score 0):

JamPlus has a built-in workspace generator that reads a project's Jamfiles and exports an IDE workspace. 
http://jamplus.org/git/jamplus/docs/html/jamtoworkspace.html